# is there a browserify for vite? how can I use webrtc-swarm with a vite based project?

Tags: vite, browserify, p2p

The title about says it. To use [webrtc-swarm](https://github.com/mafintosh/webrtc-swarm) I believe that you need browserify -- Buffer is needed to be globally defined, and although there is a handy replacement, it won't load in time to resolve its requirement just by adding code like:

```
import { Buffer } from 'buffer'
globalThis.Buffer = Buffer
```

The usage that I implemented from webrtc-swarm's readme is:

```
import swarm from 'webrtc-swarm'
import signalhub from 'signalhub'

  const hub = signalhub('swarm-example', [clientOpts.server])
  const swarmClient = swarm(hub)
```

the error that I see is:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Buffer is undefined
    js index.js:12
    __require2 chunk-TFWDKVI3.js:18
    js browser.js:15
    __require2 chunk-TFWDKVI3.js:18
    js index.js:6
    __require2 chunk-TFWDKVI3.js:18
    js index.js:1
    __require2 chunk-TFWDKVI3.js:18
    <anonymous> webrtc-swarm.js:1620
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't exactly a browserify equivalent in Vite; instead you can try one of the multiple strategies with **aliases** and **polyfills**. The simplest thing you should try first is using a vite plugin like [vite-plugin-node-polyfills](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-node-polyfills) or [vite-plugin-node-stdlib-browser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-node-stdlib-browser).

```js
// vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import { nodePolyfills } from 'vite-plugin-node-polyfills'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    nodePolyfills({
      // Whether to polyfill `node:` protocol imports.
      protocolImports: true,
    }),
  ],
})
```

If this doesn't work then, you can try combination of rollup based plugins. When you wish to provide [own implementation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-polyfill-node) for a core node.js module like `events`, then you can use [`resolve.alias`](https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#resolve-alias) along with your own polyfill to achieve this:

```js
// vite.config.js

export default {
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      // Ensure that you install 'rollup-plugin-polyfill-node' package
      'events': 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/events',
    }
}
```

The same [`rollup-plugin-node-polyfills`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-polyfill-node) can also be used as direct Vite plugin:

```js
// vite.config.js
import nodePolyfills from 'rollup-plugin-polyfill-node';

export default {
  plugins: [
    // Automatically polyfill all the core node.js modules
    // May or may not be desirable depending on the required build.
    // Also polyfill globals like `process` and `Buffer`.
    nodePolyfills({})
  ]
}
```

If your rollup plugin doesn't work this way, you can use more [low-level API](https://vitejs.dev/guide/api-plugin.html#rollup-plugin-compatibility) to use rollup plugin using `build.rollupOptions.plugins` configuration options.

Finally, if you are just looking to patch global objects like `Buffer` and `process`, you can try [rollup inejct](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rollup/plugin-inject) plugin.

> On a side note, even though Vite.js uses ESBuild under the hood, ESBuild plugins cannot be used with Vite as it uses the [transform API](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/2238#issuecomment-808943494).